# Trouble creating SQL Query to update line item amounts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm going to preface this question with the disclaimer that creating what I call "complex" queries isn't in my forte. Most of the time, there is a much simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish so if the below query isn't up to par, I apologize.

With that said, I have a table that keeps track of Vendor Invoices and Vendor Invoice Items (along with a Vendor Invoice Type and Vendor Invoice Item Type). Our bookkeeper wants a report that simply shows: Vendor | Location | Inv Number | Inv Type | Item Type | Inv Date | Rental Fee | Restock Fee | Shipping Fee | Line Item Cost | Total (Line Item + Fees)

Most of the time, one vendor invoice is one line. However, there are exceptions where a vendor invoice can have many item types, thus creating two rows. Not a big deal EXCEPT the fees (Rental, Restock, Shipping) are attached to the Vendor Invoice table. So, I first created a query that checks the temp table for Invoices that have multiple rows, takes the last row, and zero's out the fees. So that only one line item would have the fee. However, our bookkeeper doesn't like that. Instead, she'd like the fees to be "distributed" among the line items.

So, if a vendor invoice has a $25 shipping charge, has two line items, then each line item would be $12.50.

After working with the query, I got it to update the Last Row to be the adjusted amount but row 1+ would have the original amount.

I'm going to post my entire query here (again - I'm sorry that this may not be the best looking query; however, suggestions are always welcome)

```
DROP TABLE #tVendorInvoiceReport
DROP TABLE #tSummary

SELECT  v.Name AS Vendor ,
    vii.Location ,
    vi.VendorInvNumber ,
    vit.Descr AS InvoiceType ,
    vii.VendorInvoiceItemType ,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), vi.VendorInvDate, 120) VendorInvDate ,
    vi.RentalFee ,
    vi.RestockFee ,
    vi.ShippingFee ,
    SUM(vii.TotalUnitCost) TotalItemCost ,
    CONVERT(MONEY, 0) TotalInvoice  ,
    RowID = IDENTITY( INT,1,1)
INTO    #tVendorInvoiceReport
FROM    dbo.vVendorInvoiceItems AS vii
    JOIN dbo.VendorInvoices AS vi ON vii.VendorInvID = vi.VendorInvID
    JOIN dbo.Vendors AS v ON vi.VendorID = v.VendorID
    JOIN dbo.VendorInvoiceTypes AS vit ON vi.VendorInvTypeID = vit.VendorInvTypeID
WHERE   vi.VendorInvDate >= '2012-01-01'
    AND vi.VendorInvDate <= '2012-01-31'
GROUP BY v.Name ,
    vii.Location ,
    vi.VendorInvNumber ,
    vit.Descr ,
    vii.VendorInvoiceItemType ,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), vi.VendorInvDate, 120) ,
    vi.RentalFee ,
    vi.RestockFee ,
    vi.ShippingFee
ORDER BY v.Name ,
    vii.Location ,
    vi.VendorInvNumber ,
    vit.Descr ,
    vii.VendorInvoiceItemType ,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), vi.VendorInvDate, 120)


SELECT  VendorInvNumber ,
    COUNT(RowID) TotalLines ,
    MAX(RowID) LastLine
INTO    #tSummary
FROM    #tVendorInvoiceReport
GROUP BY VendorInvNumber

WHILE ( SELECT  COUNT(LastLine)
    FROM    #tSummary AS ts
    WHERE   TotalLines > 1
  ) > 0 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LastLine INT
    DECLARE @NumItems INT

    SET @LastLine = ( SELECT    MAX(LastLine)
                      FROM      #tSummary AS ts
                      WHERE     TotalLines > 1
                    )

    SET @NumItems = ( SELECT    COUNT(VendorInvNumber)
                      FROM      #tVendorInvoiceReport
                      WHERE     VendorInvNumber IN (
                                SELECT  VendorInvNumber
                                FROM    #tSummary
                                WHERE   LastLine = @LastLine )
                    ) 

    UPDATE  #tVendorInvoiceReport
    SET     RentalFee = ( RentalFee / @NumItems ) ,
            RestockFee = ( RestockFee / @NumItems ) ,
            ShippingFee = ( ShippingFee / @NumItems )
    WHERE   RowID = @LastLine

    DELETE  FROM #tSummary
    WHERE   LastLine = @LastLine

    --PRINT @NumItems
END

UPDATE  #tVendorInvoiceReport
SET     TotalInvoice = ( TotalItemCost + RentalFee + RestockFee + ShippingFee )

SELECT  Vendor ,
    Location ,
    VendorInvNumber ,
    InvoiceType ,
    VendorInvoiceItemType ,
    VendorInvDate ,
    RentalFee ,
    RestockFee ,
    ShippingFee ,
    TotalItemCost ,
    TotalInvoice
FROM    #tVendorInvoiceReport AS tvir
```

I sincerely appreciate anyone who took the time to read this and attempt to point me in the right direction.

Thank you,
Andrew

PS - I did try and remove "WHERE RowID = @LastLine" from the first Update, but that changed the Shipping Fees for the first line with two items to "0.0868" instead of 12.50 ($25/2)

Comment: Please create a simpler example, show table structure, and sample data before and after the update.

Comment: I wasn't completely sure how to convey exactly what I needed without the example posted. I was about to type some example data, but thankfully @jim31415 helped me out. Thank you for looking into this post though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to split something like an invoice shipping fee over one or more invoice items.

I created some sample invoice and invoice item tables shown below and used the 
[over(partition) clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to split out the shipping per item.

```
-- sample tables
declare @Invoice table (InvoiceID int, customerID int, Date datetime, ShippingFee float)
declare @InvoiceItem table (InvoiceItemID int identity, InvoiceID int, ItemDesc varchar(50), Quantity float, ItemPrice float)

-- Example 1
insert @Invoice values(1, 800, getdate(), 20);
insert @InvoiceItem values(1, 'Widget', 1, 10.00)
insert @InvoiceItem values(1, 'Wing Nut', 5, 2.00)
insert @InvoiceItem values(1, 'Doodad', 8, 0.50)
insert @InvoiceItem values(1, 'Thingy', 3, 1.00)

-- Example 2
insert @Invoice values(2, 815, getdate(), 15);
insert @InvoiceItem values(2, 'Green Stuff', 10, 1.00)
insert @InvoiceItem values(2, 'Blue Stuff', 10, 1.60)

-- Example 3
insert @Invoice values(3, 789, getdate(), 15);
insert @InvoiceItem values(3, 'Widget', 10, 1.60)

-- query
select 
    n.InvoiceID,
    n.InvoiceItemID,
    n.ItemDesc,
    n.Quantity,
    n.ItemPrice,
    ExtendedPrice = n.Quantity *    n.ItemPrice,
    Shipping = i.ShippingFee / count(n.InvoiceItemID) over(partition by n.InvoiceID)
from @InvoiceItem n
    join @Invoice i on i.InvoiceID = n.InvoiceID
```

Output:

```
    InvoiceID   InvoiceItemID   ItemDesc    Quantity    ItemPrice   ExtendedPrice   Shipping
    1           1               Widget      1           10          10                  5
    1           2               Wing Nut    5           2           10                  5
    1           3               Doodad      8           0.5         4                   5
    1           4               Thingy      3           1           3                   5

    2           5               Green Stuff 10          1           10                  7.5
    2           6               Blue Stuff  10          1.6         16                  7.5

    3           7               Widget      10          1.6         16                  15
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I know my question wasn't the clearest and I didn't define a table structure or a data set (which I probably should have done), but you are one of the many reasons why Stack Overflow is simply an incredibly resource. I implemented your logic into my query and it works beautifully. In addition, you've taught me a new function (over & partition by). Thank you.